what's difference between "Res" get by adb shell top and "Rss" get by adb dumpsys meminfo when I test my Android app performance


RSS is the total memory actually held in RAM for a process.
PSS differs from RSS in that it reports the proportional size of its shared libraries
RES it refers to the virtual address already mapped to physical address and it still in RAM.
so，I think RES is equivalent to Rss or Pss brefore,but in my testing is not

Best way would be to check the source code of dumpsys command. As AOSP sources are public you can check how dumpsys gets it's values.

Related: How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?
